# WordPress Redirect Post_ID

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I moved my WordPress installation into a subfolder (/wp) on my site. I now need to create a rewrite rule that points all links to that. Example: http://www.domain.com/1234 --> http://www.domain.com/wp/1234 (where 1234 is the post_id). Of course, I have over 15000 posts, so I can't rewrite each, so I need a rule that can do a generic "1", "2", etc. and add the other numbers of the post and redirect them appropriately.

I've been researching rewrite rules all day and have had no luck. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your .htaccess file in the root:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$ wp/$1 [L,R,QSA]
```

Comment: Well, what didn't work? Where are you putting this in the .htaccess file? Where is the .htaccess file? Are you sure it's being read and processed? What is the rewritten/redirected URL?